Why is arg/3 faster when its third argument is an unbound variable?
Predicates ksort/3 and fksort/3 sort lists of Key-Value pairs, where Key is a value between 1 and a small integer MaxKey.
% first version

ksort(MaxKey, List, Sorted) :-
    create(MaxKey, Buckets),
    scatter(List, Buckets),
    gather(Buckets, Sorted).

scatter([], _).
scatter([Key-Val|Pairs], Buckets) :-
    arg(Key, Buckets, Head-[Key-Val|Tail]),
    setarg(Key, Buckets, Head-Tail),
    scatter(Pairs, Buckets).

% second version

fksort(MaxKey, List, Sorted) :-
    create(MaxKey, Buckets),
    fscatter(List, Buckets),
    gather(Buckets, Sorted).

fscatter([], _).
fscatter([Key-Val|Pairs], Buckets) :-
    arg(Key, Buckets, Bucket),        % <= third argument is an unbound variable
    setarg(Key, Buckets, Head-Tail),
    Bucket = Head-[Key-Val|Tail],
    fscatter(Pairs, Buckets).

% predicates used in both versions

create(MaxKey, Buckets) :-
    findall(L-L, between(1, MaxKey, _), Dlists),
    Buckets =.. [buckets|Dlists].

gather(Buckets, Sorted) :-
    Buckets =.. [buckets|Dlists],
    join(Dlists, Sorted).

join([], []).
join([Head-Tail|Dlists], Head) :-
    join(Dlists, Tail).

comparison :-
    K = 100,
    format('size keysort ksort fksort\n'),
    forall( between(15, 22, I),
            (   garbage_collect,
                N is 2^I,
                randpairs(N, K, L),
                timeit(10, keysort,   L, S1, T1),
                timeit(10, ksort(K),  L, S2, T2),
                timeit(10, fksort(K), L, S3, T3),
                S1 = S2,
                S2 = S3,
                format('2^~w    ~2f  ~2f   ~2f\n', [I, T1, T2, T3]) ) ).

randpairs(N, K, Pairs) :-
    findall(Key-Val,
            ( between(1, N, _),
              random_between(1, K, Key),
              random(Val) ),
            Pairs).

timeit(R, P, L, S, T) :-
    garbage_collect,
    Start is cputime,
    forall(between(1, R, _), call(P, L, S)),
    T is (cputime - Start)/R.

In this specific scenario, both predicates run faster than the ISO built-in predicate keysort/2.
?- comparison.
size keysort ksort fksort
2^15    0.01  0.01   0.00
2^16    0.02  0.02   0.01
2^17    0.05  0.03   0.02
2^18    0.12  0.06   0.03
2^19    0.30  0.12   0.06
2^20    0.69  0.23   0.13
2^21    1.56  0.42   0.26
2^22    3.56  0.93   0.52
true.

The only difference between ksort/3 and fksort/3 is how they call the predicate arg/3. My question is: why fksort/3 is faster than ksort/3?

In the scatter/2 predicate, the third argument in the arg/3 call, Head-[Key-Val|Tail], requires traversing a compound term to access four sub-terms, which is more computationally expensive than a variable argument as in the call from the fscatter/3 predicate. The fscatter/3 moves the argument unification from arg/3 to an explicit unification, Bucket = Head-[Key-Val|Tail], which seems to have a performance advantage.

Seems like a performance bug in swi-prolog.

In both cases, the unification with the term  Head-[Key-Val|Tail] needs to be done. It doesn't seem to make sense that the point at which this is done could affect the runtime that much. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Actually, it does make sense. When unifications are performed in the implementation of built-in predicates such as arg/3, and depending on the implementation language, you may need to e.g. de-reference arguments before you can unify them. If an explicit unification avoids or requires less de-referencing operations, that can explain performance differences.
